# Hibernate semantics for create followed by update before flush

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-6.x

I want to create a row in the DB that tracks a job that is submitted to an SQS queue. I thought that I would be able to do this in Hibernate with code along the lines of:

```java
  @Transactional
  public GeneratedDocument createGeneratedDocument() {
    GeneratedDocument generatedDocument = new GeneratedDocument();
    // Save it so it gets an id, but it is not flushed to the db yet
    generatedDocumentRepository.save(generatedDocument);

    SendMessageResponse response = sqsClient.sendMessage(builder -> 
        builder.queueUrl(documentQueueUrl)
            // include the id in the sqs message
            .messageBody(getMessage(generatedDocument.id()));

    // re-save the document after setting the `messageId` field
    generatedDocument.setMessageId(response.messageId())
    generatedDocumentRepository.save(generatedDocument);
    return generatedDocument; // <- execution makes it past this line in the debugger
  }
```

With the entity:

```java
@Entity
public class GeneratedDocument {

  @Id @GeneratedValue private long id;

  @Column(name = "message_id", nullable = false)
  private String messageId;
...
```

This throws an error **after** returning from `createGeneratedDocument` when Hibernate is completing the transaction. I expect the insert to happen at this point. However, at that time `messageId` has been set on the Entity to a non-null value, and the entity has been re-saved.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "message_id" of relation "generated_document" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (1, 1, null, SALES_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT, null, null, null).
    at app//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2713)
    at app//org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2401)
```

And if you look at the sql that was sent, indeed `message_id` was null:

```
2023-05-25 14:05:56.290  INFO 48360 --- [    Test worker] n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener      : 
  Name:ds, Connection:32, Time:30, Success:False, Type:Prepared, Batch:True, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:1, 
  Query:["insert into generated_document (bol_shipment_id,completed_location,error,message_id,tenant_id,type,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"], 
  Params:[(NULL(BIGINT),NULL(VARCHAR),NULL(VARCHAR),NULL(VARCHAR),1,SALES_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT,1)]
                                           ^ messageId is NULL
```

If I remove the `NOT NULL` constraint from the table, it works. But I can see it's because Hibernate issues 2 sql statements. An `INSERT` followed by an `UPDATE`:

```
2023-05-25 14:25:10.297  INFO 52913 --- [    Test worker] n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener      : Name:ds, Connection:32, Time:1, Success:True, Type:Prepared, Batch:True, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:1, Query:["insert into generated_document (bol_shipment_id,completed_location,error,message_id,tenant_id,type,id) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"], Params:[(NULL(BIGINT),NULL(VARCHAR),NULL(VARCHAR),NULL(VARCHAR),1,SALES_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT,1)]
2023-05-25 14:25:10.304  INFO 52913 --- [    Test worker] n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener      : Name:ds, Connection:32, Time:0, Success:True, Type:Prepared, Batch:True, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:1, Query:["update generated_document set completed_location=?,error=?,message_id=? where id=?"], Params:[(NULL(VARCHAR),NULL(VARCHAR),8213ba0d-52ef-4a6a-b6a8-b4246599c500,1)]
```

1. Is there a way I can still get the id ahead of time, without triggering hibernate to generate an `INSERT` followed by an `UPDATE`, and instead just do a single `INSERT`?
2. This behavior was surprising to me. I thought that hibernate would be able to tell that it has a new Entity to persist, and insert it rather than doing an insert and an update. Is there any documentation that describes what Hibernate is doing in this situation that I could refer to?